# ios7 presentViewController reverts navBar from new 64px bar back to old 44px version

Tags: objective-c, ios7, statusbar, navbar

I have an application that is supporting only ios7+ The navbar setup is using the new 64px high bar that appears beneath the status bar. Here is what it looks like when the app launches:

[image]

If I do any sort of "presentViewController", when i dismiss the view the navbar shifts back to  44px height and still appears underneath the status bar which in-turn makes all the contents of the view also shift up. Here is what that looks like:

[image]

It doesn't matter if I am presenting one of my own  views or if I simply present a UIImagePickerView, any sort of slide up modal via the navigation controller breaks the navbar setup. Any ideas on how to fix this?

A few notes:

- in plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" is set to "NO"
- navbar configured with self.navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
- I am using .xib NOT Storyboards

UPDATE:

I have the navigation controller inside of a PKRevealController (https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController). Taking the reveal controller out and just adding the nav controller to the window itself fixes the issue... why would the reveal controller cause it to behave differently?

SOLUTION:

It turned out that the PKRevealController library was causing the issue. I reworked how it was set up in the AppDelegate and that solved the problem, although it's sorta of "hacky". I put my "before" and "after" configurations below:

the initial setup was :

1. configure PKRevealController
2. configure NavController and add rootView
3. set pkreveal front view = navController
4. add reveal controller to window as windows root view

the fix is

1. create a containing NavController
2. do stpes 1-3 above
3. add pkrevealcontroller to the containing navController
4. set containing nav controller nav bar to hidden
5. add containing nav controller to window as root view

Comment: so you are trying to present a new view controller within the navigation controller by using presentViewController:animated:..?

Comment: Yes exactly i have tried [self presentView and I have also tried [self.navController presentView and they both cause the same result

Answer (score 3):

If its navigationcontroller than you can use this inside every viewcontroller's viewdidload:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but solved very easily by just setting the UINavigationBar Y-position to 20px and not to 0px. Then you have to assign the UINavigationBarDelegate to your ViewController:

```
[_navigationBar setDelegate:self];
```

Furthermore you have to add this method to your ViewController, which will be called because of the Delegate assignment:

```
-(UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and a bunch of other positioning tricks to no avail. I ended up figuring out a solution, although it's sort of "hacky". I updated the main question with my findings.